# How do I set up a SMS sender for ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: twilio, asp.net-identity

I am following [the instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/2fa?view=aspnetcore-1.1) to set up a SMS sender (using twilio) for ASP.NET Core Identity. I have a couple of questions:

1. Where can I find the interface ISmsSender?
2. Where/how do I store the secrets for the Twilio credentials? I can't find where it gives the key name for them.
3. What do I do to have the Identity code send a text? Just to verify the user's phone number (not for 2FA)?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using (the demonstrably insecure) SMS approach instead of TOTP or Fido2?

Comment: _"Where/how do I store the secrets for the Twilio credentials?"_ - in `appsettings.json` for dev and in a key-vault system in production.

Comment: _"What do I do to have the Identity code send a text? Just to verify the user's phone number (not for 2FA)?"_ - https://www.twilio.com/blog/verifying-phone-number-ownership-asp-net-core-identity-razor-pages

Comment: @Dai We'll use Authenticator for 2FA. We will use texts to remind users of upcoming events they signed up for. As to ISmsSender, we want to use twilio, not ASPSMS. Is there instructions anywhere on how to set this up with twilio? Or should we drop twilio and go with ASPSMS (all we need is texting people reminders)? And if you write an answer with that twilio blog link, I'll accept it - because that answers all of my questions. THANK YOU!

Comment: @Dai I read your bio. Life is often wonderful. You made my evening much better with your help. Take care & thanks again.

Comment: I retract my comment about `ASPSMS` - I thought that was the lib with `ISmsSender` but apparently not - [and other people have noticed too](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/7212).

Comment: @Dai Any guidance if all we care about is texting reminders - twilio or ASPSMS? And why? TIA

Comment: I’ve been happy with Twilio - I’ve been using them since ~2015ish. Except their .NET SDK’s API design is awful - I just use HttpClient directly against their web-service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASP.NET Core Identity library has removed all code & web pages for using SMS for 2FA. They did so because it's not terribly effective. So the answer to any question like this is - no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

1. Where can I find the interface ISmsSender?

It looks like the `ISmsSender` was generated by the `aspnet-codegenerator` in old versions of .NET Core. I'm not sure when they stopped adding in SMS support, but it is not included anymore in recent versions of .NET.
You should still be able to use old version of .NET and then generate the templates, but it's quite a hassle.

I'd look at the code in [this sample repo](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/security/authentication/2fa/sample/Web2FA) and copy over the relevant bits.

---

The template uses Twilio's client to send messages directly, but Twilio also offers the [Verify API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify) which is specifically designed for verification of channels like SMS, Voice, TOTP, Email, WhatsApp, Push, and Silent Network Auth, and the service offers additional features, like [Fraud Guard](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/preventing-toll-fraud/sms-fraud-guard) which could save you money if there's fraudulent SMS traffic.

The ASP.NET Core identity templates aren't designed for this service, so it'd take some more work on your behalf to integrate if you'd want to. (I should spent some time developing a tutorial for this).

Of course, you can keep using the messaging API directly or alternative SMS products if that better suits your needs.

---

2. Where/how do I store the secrets for the Twilio credentials?

Secrets should never be hardcoded or checked into source control.
For local development, the easiest option is to the [Secret Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets#secret-manager), but you can also use environment variables, or vault services.
For production environments, you can't use the secret manager, but you can still use environment variables and vault services.

If you're using the identity templates, the following object is used according to [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/2fa?view=aspnetcore-1.1).

So, based on the name of the class and properties, you'd configure the user secrets this way I think:

```bash
dotnet user-secrets set SMSoptions:SMSAccountIdentification [TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID]
dotnet user-secrets set SMSoptions:SMSAccountPassword [TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN]
```

I'd recommend deviating from their template code and register the Twilio client into ASP.NET Core's dependency injection container by using [the Twilio helper library for ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/twilio-labs/twilio-aspnet), as [documented in the README.md](https://github.com/twilio-labs/twilio-aspnet#add-the-twilio-client-to-the-aspnet-core-dependency-injection-container).
Once you add the Twilio client to the container, you can inject it into the controller where necessary and pass it as a parameter to the Twilio API calls.

---

3. What do I do to have the Identity code send a text? Just to verify the user's phone number (not for 2FA)?

I'm not sure what you mean by this. Can you clarify?

Comment: I've dropped this because Identity no longer supports SMS for 2FA. Thanks for the answers.